# How to match the string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a function to match the string but not getting expected result. I am new in python

Please suggest how will get expected result

I have done so far.

**Script**

```
g4 = 'NKXD'
protein = 'SMQTIKCVVVGDGAVGKTCLLISYTTNKFPSEYVPTVFDNYAVTVMIGGEPYTLGLFDTAGQEDYDRLRPLSYPQTDVFLVCFSVVSPSSFENVKEKWVPEITHHCPKTPFLLVGTQIDLRDDPSTIEKLAKNKQKPITPETAEKLARDLKAVKYVECSALTQKGLKNVFDEAILAALEPPEPKKSRRCVLL'

def g4_match(g4,protein):
  N = "NTAG"
  K = "KLQ"
  D = "DE"
  spl_mismatch, mismatch = (0,0)
  for x,y in zip(g4,protein):
    if not (x == 'X' or y == x):
      if(x == 'T' and y in N):
        spl_mismatch+=1
      elif(x == 'L' and y in K):
        spl_mismatch+=1
      elif(x == 'E' and y in D):
        spl_mismatch+=1
      else:
        mismatch+=1
    if mismatch > 0 or spl_mismatch > 2:
        return False
  return True

print g4_match(g4,protein)
```

**Currently Getting output**

```
((10, 'GDGAVGK'), (57, 'DTAG'), (132, 'NKQK'), (156, 'ECSAL'))
((10, 'GDGAVGK'), (63, 'DYDR'), (132, 'NKQK'), (156, 'ECSAL'))
((10, 'GDGAVGK'), (65, 'DRLR'), (132, 'NKQK'), (156, 'ECSAL'))
((10, 'GDGAVGK'), (76, 'DVFL'), (132, 'NKQK'), (156, 'ECSAL'))
```

**But expected output is:**

```
N="TAG"
K="LQ"
D="E"
```

In third column there is `NKQK` but it can be `NKXD` X can be any string in this case there is no mismatch or `TLXD` and `ALXD` and `GLXD` and `TQXD` and `AQXD` and `GQXD` and `NLXE` and `NQXE`.I need like that output in third column if match from input.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. There's a lot of unnecessary code here.

Comment: I have edited my question, please suggest me something

Comment: I don't see any edits...

Comment: Why is this tagged with Python 2.7 *and* Python 3...? Which is it>

Comment: dear,  i can use both

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, please let me know unnecessary code here

Comment: @user8866270 if your `g4_match()` is not returning as expected then probably you should only show that function alone with the required input and output.

Comment: Please see [mcve]

Comment: I edited my question, please check

Comment: @user8866270 please go through the link coLDsPEED shared. The updated script doesn't help, neither you're calling `g4_match()`, nor you've shared the input and output specific to `g4_match()`

Comment: You removed necessary code (for further readers, the full script is available in old revisions). But the expected output look unrelated to both the question title and the script. With or without your edits, the question is *unclear*.

Comment: Please suggest How will get expected result? I edited my question again